# CodeIgniter - Blank page on database autoload

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, autoload

I encouter a problem since this morning, after I migrated my website from my local machine to the server.

To replace the context, I developed a website with the framework CodeIgniter, and everything before the migration was working fine.

After a long research, it seems that when i put this :

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

I have a blank page on my website, without any php/ci errors in the logs.

And if I let this :

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array();
```

The website is working correctly (well, I can't log in but I don't have a blank page).

I added the mysql.so in the php.ini file, but it didn't help me neither.

Does someone already encountered this problem ? How can you solved it please ?

Thanks !

B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your db connection credentials are correct? If you switchd servers this seems like it might be the issue.

Additionally, CodeIgniter sets error_reporting(0) for production environments --- hence the blank page. Check your logs dir (is it writeable by the webserver process..?) for any other info.

Comment: I tried to connect with the commandline and everything was OK so I presume it won't be a problem to have the same credentials in database.php file

Comment: I also have : error_reporting(E_ALL); and the only line in the log concerning the db is : DEBUG - 2011-07-13 16:37:57 --> Database Driver Class Initialized

Comment: search your app (from the root dir) for any other instances of "error_reporting" -- CI may be overriding the setting after you

Comment: check your webserver or php logs, (php log location should be visible in php.ini), webserver logs location depend on the server..

Comment: That's what I said in the post, I have no php or apache errors :(

Comment: No i don't have anything of it.

Comment: OK it seems to be a mysql error. I remove the @ before the mysql_connect in the system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php and I got this error : Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in path_to_my_site/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php on line 70. I'll check for the mysql version then...

Answer (score 7):

in application/config/database.php
check that

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

is set to

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with blank pages seemingly associated with loading the database, be it via autoload or calling `$this->load->database();` in the model constructor.  I ended up having to modify my 'php.ini' file by commenting out `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` and uncommenting `extension=php_mysql.dll` (i.e. turning PDO back off).  I am running Windows 8.1, Apache 2.2, and PHP 5.3.27.

This answer is similar to another, but I couldn't add a comment for clarification since I just signed up.  It took me a couple of hours and a lot of Googling to resolve, so hopefully this helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Please restart your webserver and try again.

create a new info.php file with phpinfo();

> ```
> <?php
>
> phpinfo();
>
> ?>
> ```

see if the mysql extension is loading if its loading

try to do a chmod 0777 to your directoy

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you don't have mysql module for php installed. In windows, I believe this comes with the php installer. If you are on linux, for example on Fedora, this is how you install it:

`sudo yum -y install php-mysql`

Restart the webserver after the installation. Assuming you are using apache httpd:

`sudo service httpd restart`

Now you should see the pages again (assuming you have correct settings in conf/database.php).

Answer (score 1):

I have just had this error, after debugging the MYSQL driver I figure out the problem.

The problem was that on the database config file I was using MYSQL as a driver when on the server it has installed MYSQLI, just change it on the config file and you're done.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your database is not configured properly and your PHP installation is blocking the errors.

Take a look at your log files or try putting

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
```

in your `index.php` and see what you get

Comment: that is turned off in codeigniter configuration, that won't work

Comment: The db parameters seems to be OK as I can connect it with the commandline, and I can reached it on my machine. The DB server is not local aswell.

Answer (score 0):

For me, having the same issue using Z-WAMP, had to uncomment "extension=php_mysql.dll" from the php.ini. Also assigned "mysql.default_port = 3306" and "mysql.default_host = localhost". Hope it helps someone out there

Answer (score 0):

For those using linux (esp. ubuntu) and are still getting the blank page, do the following:

1. `sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql php5-cli mysql-server`
2. `sudo service apache2 restart`
3. `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');`

Answer (score 0):

Installing php5-pgsql fixed it for me (on Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

just go to application/config/database.php and find

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

Replace `'mysql'` with `'mysqli'`

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

and that's it!